# Cómo realizar una selección de ciertas filas específicas en una matriz?

Tags: python, numpy, matriz

Basicamente tengo un ejercicio hipotético que consiste en lo siguiente:

Asumiendo (es decir que ya existen estas matrices y listas en su programa, no es necesario crearlas) que para el mes de abril tiene las siguientes dos matrices:

**m_paq_recibidos**, cuyas filas representan los barrios y cuyas columnas representan los días del mes. Las celdas son el número de paquetes entregados en ese barrio ese día del mes.

**m_paq_enviados**, cuyas filas representan los barrios y las columnas representan los tipos de artículo. Las celdas son el número de paquetes de cada tipo que salieron de ese barrio.

y las siguientes listas de etiquetas:

**l_etq_barrios** (etiquetas de filas para ambas matrices)

**l_etq_tipo** (etiqueta de columnas de la segunda matriz).

#Ejercicio 1:

**Muestre por pantalla los nombres de los 6 barrios en los que se entregaron más paquetes en los primeros 18 días del mes.**

#Ejercicio 2:

**Muestre por pantalla cuál es el tipo de artículo que más se envía desde cada uno de los barrios mostrados en el numeral 4.**

Adjunto mi código:

```
#Ejercicio 1
arr_barrios = np.array(lst_etq_barrios)
top_6 = arr_barrios[np.argsort(np.sum(m_paq_recibidos[:,:18],axis=1))[::-1][:6]]
print(top_6)
#Ejercicio 2
arr_tipos = np.array(lst_etq_tipo)
for barrio in top_6:
  indice = np.where(barrio == arr_barrios)
  seleccion = m_paq_enviados[indice,:]
```

Justo en esta ultima parte no se como continuar, pues si bien se seleccionan las filas que quiero no se como realizar la suma por columnas correspondiente, ya que de la forma en que lo estoy haciendo me va botando vector por vector, y yo quiero una selección directa de la matriz. No se si me hago entender correctamente.
Necesito esto para luego indexarla al arreglo de tipos y obtener mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debe haber varias formas de resolverlo. Esta podría ser una opción:

```
filtro = [elem in top_6 for elem in l_etq_barrios]

indices_max = np.argmax(m_paq_enviados[filtro], axis=1)
mas_enviados = l_etq_tipos[indices_max]
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).